# using threads on perl/tk to avoid window freeze/not responding

Tags: mysql, perl, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use threading in my perl/tk application so that it won't freeze while connecting to a remote mysql server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use Tk;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

our $type="mysql";
our $database="b_db";
our $host="mysite.com";
our $port="3306";
our $tablename="tc";
our $user="example";
our $pwd="********";
our $dsn="dbi:$type:$database:$host:$port";

my $thr=threads->create(\&con);

our $mw=new MainWindow;
$mw->Button(-text=>"Connect",-command=>\&con)->pack;
MainLoop; 
sub con{
    our $connect=DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$pwd)or die &mysql_Err;
    print "done connecting\n" if $connect;
    print "error\n" unless $connect;
}
$thr->detach;
```

but it still freezes when it tries to connect. I have tried to use tk/fileevent:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use Tk;

our $type="mysql";
our $database="b_db";
our $host="mysite.com";
our $port="3306";
our $tablename="tc";
our $user="example";
our $pwd="********";
our $dsn="dbi:$type:$database:$host:$port";

our $mw=new MainWindow;
$mw->Button(-text=>"Connect",-command=>\&con)->pack;

sub con{
    our $connect=DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$pwd)or die &mysql_Err;
    $mw->fileevent($connect, "readable", \&contquery);
}

sub contquery{
    $query="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id";
    $queryhandle=$connect->prepare($query);
    $queryhandle->execute;
    $queryhandle->bind_columns(undef, \$product_id, \$price, \$product_name,  \product_type);
    while($queryhandle->fetch()){
        print <<print;
Product Name: $product_name | Type: $product_type | Prict: $price
print
    }
}
MainLoop;
```

but it still freezes. Can anyone advise me on what might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

See [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org//?node_id=732294): Tk isn't thread-safe.

1. Create the thread before any Tk widgets are created.
2. Don't touch any Tk objects from the thread, use shared variables for communication.

Comment: hey! please give me an example of code so that i could build a little algorithm for that because i tried making $connect as a shared variable but it still freezes while waiting for connection to finish

Comment: nice link perlmonks comments are very useful for perl/tk & thread starters!

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding threading and sharing. `our` doesn't share across threads. You need to declare a variable as `shared` in order to do that.

Otherwise from the moment you `create` the subthread, they have their own local copy of all the variables. This will almost certainly be your problem - your thread connects to the database then exits, completely independent of the main thread.

[`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) also doesn't do what you think it does - that's for sharing package variables (e.g. nothing at all to do with threading), which is irrelevant in your code. Stick with `my`.

You *might* be able to do:

```
my $db_handle : shared;
```

And then in the thread:

```
$db_handle = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
```

But bear in mind you cannot be sure when that'll complete, so it's very important you check before you try and use it in another thread.

Comment: but it's still freezes while connecting to remote DB i just did what you told me i just changed, my $connect:shared